# push or addToSet is not working with express, node and mongoose(getting response { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 })

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update the document while using push and addToSet but it is not updating any data!

here is my schema

```
var attendance_list = new Schema({
"username":{
    type:String,
    unique:true
}});
```

and here how I am trying to update!

```
attedanceAtDb.update({"username":"test"},{
       $addToSet:{
                "pushtest":"test"
           }
    }
     ,(err,result)=>{
         if(err){
             reject(err);
         }else{
             resolve(result);
         }
     })
```

and this is the response

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

Thanks in advance for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) required array format in param. Try as below:

```
attedanceAtDb.findOneAndUpdate({"username":"test"},{
       $addToSet:{
                "pushtest": ["test"]
           }
    },{upsert: true, new: true}
     ,(err,result)=>{
         if(err){
             reject(err);
         }else{
             resolve(result);
         }
     })
```

Comment: one question? in while using mongoose in express do we need to make sure that the field we are pushing should be already defined in the Shema?

Comment: Firstly you have to define it in your schema and secondly you can use option { upsert: true } to add field if it does not exist in your document.

Comment: option {upsert: true} will add new document if query part does not match any document and {new: true } will give you updated document.

Answer (score 0):

Your Schema should be like this,

```
var attendance_list = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    pushtest: []
});
```

Hope it helps...